# Match specific pattern that does not contain other pattern in one expression

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm looking for a regex to use in [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) location matching, that would match a specified end pattern not being anywhere preceded by a specified other pattern.

Like, I have files:

```
webgl-0.4.0-alpha.1-gzip-dev/streaming-wasm-gzip-dev.wasm.framework.unityweb
webgl-0.4.0-alpha.1-gzip-dev/streaming-wasm-gzip-dev.data.unityweb

webgl-0.4.0-alpha.1-gzip/streaming-wasm-gzip.wasm.framework.unityweb
webgl-0.4.0-alpha.1-gzip/streaming-wasm-gzip.data.unityweb
```

I want to match all `\.unityweb` except those that are anywhere preceded by `dev`. Basically, I need to match last two lines. I cannot hardcode it, as the files/directories might be named arbitrary.

The usual `((?!dev\/).)*$` doesn't suffice, because it still gets the ends. `(?<!dev)` also cannot be added anwyhere as it will only match directly before.

I am out of clues and also out of regex fu!

The solution does not have to be strictly regex, might be nginx based too.

It might have been asked before, but I cannot seem to know the correct keywords to find it.

Comment: Try `^(?>[^d\r\n]+|d(?!ev))*$` https://regex101.com/r/aukykp/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^(?!.*?dev\/.*).+\.unityweb$
```

[See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/CeGcB1/4)

**Description:**

- `^` From the start of the line
- `(?! _______ )`  Negative Lookahead
- `.*?dev\/` Match any character any amount of times, until you reach dev followed by a slash
- `.*` Match any characters any amount of times
- Negative lookahead closes
- `.+` Match any character, more than once
- `\.unityweb` - until you reach .unityweb
- `$` End of the line

  Use the full match for what you need

**EDIT**

Just realised that you also state a contradiction in your question, as you say you don't want to match anything preceded by `dev/` but you also want to match the first two examples you gave.

That can be done by changing the negative lookahead to a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*?dev\/.*).+\.unityweb$
```

[See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/CeGcB1/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
^(?!.*dev.*\.unityweb)(?=.*\.unityweb).*$
```

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKNuM5/2/)